# Retrieving the state(checked/unchecked) of a checkbox column in datagridview in ADO.NET

Tags: checkbox, ado.net

I have added a DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn in a datagridview and want to commit changes in database on checking and unchecking this checkboxcolumn. Please assist.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
}

private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value);
}
```

in CellValueChanged Event you can retrieve the changed value only if you called CommitEdit before ...